# Extracting hidden features from Autoencoders using Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, autoencoder

Following the tutorials in this [post](https://medium.com/pytorch/implementing-an-autoencoder-in-pytorch-19baa22647d1), I am trying to train an autoencoder and extract the features from its hidden layer.

So here are my questions:

1. In the autoencoder class, there is a "forward" function. However, I cannot see anywhere in the code that this function is called. So how does it get trained?
2. My question above is because I feel if I want to extract the features, I should add another function (f"orward_hidden") in the autoencoder class:

   ```
    def forward(self, features):
        #print("in forward")
        #print(type(features))
        activation = self.encoder_hidden_layer(features)
        activation = torch.relu(activation)
        code = self.encoder_output_layer(activation)
        code = torch.relu(code)
        activation = self.decoder_hidden_layer(code)
        activation = torch.relu(activation)
        activation = self.decoder_output_layer(activation)
        reconstructed = torch.relu(activation)
        return reconstructed

    def forward_hidden(self, features):
        activation = self.encoder_hidden_layer(features)
        activation = torch.relu(activation)
        code = self.encoder_output_layer(activation)
        code = torch.relu(code)
        return code
   ```

Then, after training, which means after this line in the main code:

```
print("AE, epoch : {}/{}, loss = {:.6f}".format(epoch + 1, epochs_AE, loss))
```

I can put the following code to retrieve the features from the hidden layer:

```
hidden_features = model_AE.forward_hidden(my_input)
```

Is this way correct? Still, I am wondering how the "forward" function was used for training. Because I cannot see it anywhere in the code that is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forward` is the essence of your model and actually defines what the model does.

It is implicetly called with `model(input)` during the training.

If you are askling how to extract  intermediate features after running the model, you can register a **forward-hook** like described [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-l-load-my-best-model-as-a-feature-extractor-evaluator/17254/6), that will "catch" the values for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. So you mean "forward" is implicitly called because of nn module of Pytorch? (some kind of properties of that?)
Does it mean we cannot add other arbitrary functions?
I am still a bit confused.

Comment: forward() is a method you MUST implement (an interface in some languages like Java).
this is expected by the pytorch framework implementors. Other than this you can add anthing you like but it is not going to be used by pytorch. Instead of this the implemntors have used the hook (or callback) pattern to let you "hook" your function "outside" the model class

Comment: Do you have any other recommendation/examples that show how to hook other functions in the nn models?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a class with `nn.Module` when working with PyTorch, the forward function is called implicitly and you do not need to separately call it.